# Optimized solution to find distinct squares of 2X2 in a matrix of 0s and 1s

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

A boolean matrix of size MXN is given. Find max possible 2X2 squares of 0s in given matrix?

Example input:

```
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

possible solutions

> [image]
>
> and
>
> [image]

In upper 2 possible solutions, in 1st we made only 2 squares but in 2nd we made 3 squares. Max possible squares are 3 in upper example.

Answer : 3

Please help to find out some optimized solution of the problem.

Comment: Updated question. Removed images.

Answer (score 2):

This is the optimization variant of [set packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing), in which you have a set S of sets, and the goal is get the biggest subset of S such that its elements are pairwise disjoint. The decision variant asks whether there is such a subset of size k, and is NP-complete, making the optimization variant NP-hard. The sets here are always exactly 4 elements, which is still NP-hard (it wouldn't be if the sets had exactly 2 elements, which is an easy problem).

One possible way to solve it could be to use integer linear programming, such as:

Let the variable x[i] decide whether to take a particular 2x2 square.

```
maximize sum(x[i])

subject to
x[i] in {0, 1}
if x[i] and x[j] correspond to overlapping squares, x[i] + x[j] <= 1
```

You can make the fact that no 1's may be covered a constraint here too, but you might as well not even consider the 2x2 squares that would cover one or more 1's.

Comment: While you didn't say so explicitly, it might sounds like it follows from your argument that the problem is NP-hard, which it doesn't, because not arbitrary set packing instances can be generated.

Comment: @FalkHüffner that's why I added that last sentence of the first paragraph

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-hard, as shown [here](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1321&context=cstech). Thus, you won't find an algorithm that is always fast and optima. The article suggests a factor-2 approximation, which might be good enough for your purpose.